# Converting date and time format when importing csv file in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, date, datetime

I haven't been able to find a solution in similar questions yet so I'll have to give it a go here.
I am importing a csv file looking like this in notepad:

```
",""ItemName"""
"Time,""Raw Values"""
"7/19/2019  10:31:29 PM,"" 0"","
"7/19/2019  10:32:01 PM,"" 1"","
```

What I want when I save it as a new csv, is to reformat the date/time and the corresponding value to this (required by analysis software): The semicolon as separator and in the end is important, and I don't really need a header.

```
2019-07-19 22:31:29;0;
2019-07-19 22:32:01;1;
```

This is what it looks like in Python:

```
Item1 = pd.read_csv(r'.\Datafiles\ItemName.csv')
Item1

#Output:
# ,"ItemName"
# 0 Time,"Raw Values"
# 1 7/19/2019 10:31:29 AM," 0",
# 2 7/19/2019 10:32:01 AM," 1",

valve_G1.dtypes
# ,"ItemName"    object
# dtype: object
```

I have tried using datetime without any luck but there might be something fishy with the datatypes that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want in principle is read to DataFrame, convert datetime column and export df to csv again. I think you will need to get rid of the quote-chars to get the import correct. You can do so by reading the file content to a string, replace the '"', and feed that string to pandas.read_csv. EX:

```
import os
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# this is just to give an example:
s='''",""ItemName"""
"Time,""Raw Values"""
"7/19/2019 10:31:29 PM,"" 0"","
"7/19/2019 10:32:01 PM,"" 1"","'''
f = StringIO(s)
# in your script, make f a file pointer instead, e.g.
# with open('path_to_input.csv', 'r') as f:

# now get rid of the "
csvcontent = ''
for row in f:
    csvcontent += row.replace('"', '')
        
# read to DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csvcontent), sep=',', skiprows=1, index_col=False)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

# save cleaned output as ;-separated csv
dst = 'path_where_to_save.csv'
df.to_csv(dst, index=False, sep=';', line_terminator=';'+os.linesep)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Is it possible to also add the semicolon at the end? Now it returns 2019-07-19 10:31:29;0 but I would really like 2019-07-19 10:31:29;0;

Comment: @Henning: sure, you could add it by specifying the line terminator to be semicolon + your OS default line separator.